# Как подключить локализации в Angular?

Tags: angularjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<p class="parent language">
  <span>Язык </span>
    <select id="language" name="language">
      <option value="ru">Русский</option>
      <option value="en">Английский</option>
      <option value="vie">Вьетнамский</option>
      <option value="zho">Китайский</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Добавил select, внутри которого варианты выбора языков. Плюс есть 4 json локализации. Нашел документацию по пакету локализации в ангуляре.

https://github.com/robisim74/angular-l10n/tree/angular_v5

https://robisim74.github.io/angular-l10n/

Но так как сам обычный верстальщик и с ангуляром не работал, тыкался, тыкался, но не могу сообразить как мне подключить эти 4 файла к моему селекту.

Answer (score 0):

Замечательная библиотека [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

Суть использования заключается в хранении json файла с ресурсами разных языков. Гайд в README.md

Comment: я скинул ссыль что мы используем, вопрос как это привязать к селекту)